# How can I attach a file to a post?

Tags: support, attachment

I want to attach some files to a post on one of Stack Exchange sites. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I suggest http://dropbox.com or http://yousendit.com.

Comment: <a href="http://file">file</a>

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use a file upload service like SkyDrive and post the link on the page like so:

```
<a href="http://file">file</a>
```

Comment: I have problems with skydrive links, some users complain they can't download them. Their browser sees the skydrive URL ending in.zip and tries to download the HTML and save it as a zip.

Comment: Good file hosting sites include  [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/), [Google Drive](https://www.google.com/drive/), [OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com/about/en-us/) and [Mediafire](https://www.mediafire.com/)

Comment: And [github gists](https://gist.github.com)

Comment: @StevenVascellaro It's odd. I don't consider a single one of those to bee a good filehosting site. All to often I encounter dead links after a couple of years.

Comment: Yup, that is what happens: Dead link and useless. It is pretty stupid to not let users upload files and having to use another site to host the files. This should be integrated in this site itself. Especially which hosting site do you use? Which services will still be available years later? Nobody knows.

Answer (score 14):

Host them somewhere else and post a link. StackOverflow does not provide file hosting services.

Comment: ...and there's a reason for that!

Comment: @GeorgeEdison ... And what is the reason?

Comment: because that can get expensive and abused. They do now though, but only 1 image file up to 2mb. Drag and drop, baby!

Comment: drag'n drop of non-image files does not work, at least not in FF 56

Comment: No, storage is dirt cheap today, it is just a integral flaw of the site.

Answer (score 6):

LaTeX is just code, so if you have a question about how to do something in LaTeX, just include a snippet like you would any other piece of code.

(Hint: indent it by four spaces, or select it and click the 'binary' icon in the toolbar of the edit window.)

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) for this scenario

PS: Seems that people didn't notice that the requester was asking to include LaTeX files, which are markup based ones, thus they are plain text files!

Comment: Not relevant. Pastebin is only for text, while the question here is about **files**. Anyone can post text as part of the question/answer itself.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Latex files are simple text files, that's why I suggested PasteBin!

Comment: How is this answer different from: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/47690/158100 or the accepted answer?

Comment: @rene there are huge differences from my point of view: from the link a snippet would be useful only if it's not long, as the question body has a character limit, which I've overcome before using PasteBin and, from the accepted answered both solved the problem, but in different ways as a link to a file to download, is not a link to a site where you can actually see the file contents, maybe subtle, but the are different indeed.

Comment: Ok, I've gone the extra mile. I must be missing something. I have [pastebinned](https://pastebin.com/cGTFS2xa) a LaTeX snippet that I found on [GitHub](https://github.com/habi/latex/blob/master/boxplot.tex). What makes PasteBin now so much different then GitHub, SkyDrive, DropBox or even a [gist](https://gist.github.com/rschrieken/66ccd5743c6a6c27b3564420918912f3). So if PasteBin is so much preferable above all other filesharing options what is the extra feature that I fail to see? For a moment I thought they implemented a latex renderer or is that only available in the pro version of it?

Comment: @rene I guess from your comment that Gist is even more adequate than PasteBin for this purpose, as it's "code" related and, not just text. As PasteBin and Gist post can be done anonymously, makes them waste no space from your prefered file sharing provider (DropBox, Google Drive, etc), and makes posts discardable. Maybe it's just a subjective perspective, but makes it cleaner for me

Comment: @GonzaloVasquez; pastebin has a size limit of 500KB for the free account.