# Can Imgur handle links to PDF files?

Tags: support

On the genealogy site one often needs to include scanned image of old documents for clarity and interpretation. This is fine when working with JPEG files, but I have been working with a source that insists on downloading images as PDF files. I have no way to convert those to JPEG files locally. Is there a way to get Imgur to store these files, so that I can include a link in my questions?

Comment: Can't you screenshot the pdf? I know it's crude but it would work.

Comment: Have you considered using an external hosting service, such as OneDrive?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47689/how-can-i-attach-a-file-to-a-post

Answer (score 0):

When I need to do this at the [Genealogy & Family History Stack Exchange](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com) I just open the PDF on my laptop running Windows 7 and then use the Snipping Tool to take a screenshot of the part of the image which is relevant to my post.

I would not advise attaching PDFs or including whole images images of genealogical documents unless you have checked their Copyright.